# String interpolation for angular HTML selector

Tags: html, angular, rendering

I have many components with different selectors like app-protocol, app-inspection, app-generalview etc. I want the rendered component to be based on a variable, something like:

In Typescript

```
view = 'protocol'; // or inspection or generalview
```

In HTML

```
<app-{{view}}> </app-{{view}}>
```

or

```
<div [innerHTML] = "'<app-{{view}}>'"> </div>
```

Both HTML examples however don't work. I know I can use an *ngSwitch but I could have many cases and would like to know if there is a way to avoid doing that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe switching the selector to `[app-protocol]` (and so on), and use the tag as `<div app-protocol>` ? Never tried it, but the selector is a `querySelector` string, so this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can rended dinamically the component using `componentFactoryResolver` and `viewContainerRef`.

Here's a simple example, I've created the component called `Cmp1Component` that is going to be renderd dinamically.

App.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Cmp1Component,
    Cmp2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents:[
    Cmp1Component
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App.component.html

```
A component will be rendered down here:
<div #placeholder></div>
```

App.component.ts

```
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Cmp1Component } from './cmp1/cmp1.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public done = false;
  @ViewChild("placeholder", {read: ViewContainerRef}) placeholderRef: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver

  ) {
  }

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      if(!!this.placeholderRef && !this.done){
        this.done = true;

        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Cmp1Component);
        const componentRef = this.placeholderRef.createComponent(factory);
        componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

**One thing** : you may not need to put the logic into the `ngAfterViewChecked` cycle. I've done this logic just to show you how it works. If you actually put the code in a function that will be executed when everything is rendered, then you know for sure that `placeHolderRef` is not null or undefined.