# How to append HTML code when it's an Angular Component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, components

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6.
I have a little problem: with this simple code inside in one of my services:

```
method() {
   document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<h1>Hello</h1>');
}
```

I can dynamically display html code every time I run. 
This happens, however, only because `<h1>` is a native HTML tag. 
How can I do the same thing with an Angular component associated with an HTMML template? For example, `<myComponent></myComponent>`, 
it does not work this way ...

```
    method() {
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<myComponent>/myComponent>');
    }
```

Can you help me with a solution that uses a few lines of code? 
I have to use this method in a service. Thanks.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226385/string-interpolation-for-angular-html-selector

Comment: Thanks but I don't wont use '@ViewChild' to refer to pre-established elements. I want to use a service, not a component...